# dynamically adding elements with jQuery with classes / Wijmo tree dynamic node adding

Tags: jquery, dynamic, tree, wijmo

i am using Wijmo jQuery framework in my project and i need to render a structure tree. I am using the Wijmo tree component so the tree part is covered, but the problem arises when i need to click a node in the tree. So what i need to do is, when a node in tree is clicked, an ajax call is made that gets the structure underneath that node. The problem is

I need to somehow display the rest of the tree. The way i started this was appending the list to the parent element. This is the tree structure:

```
<div id="tree">
  <ul id="productTree">
    <li class="folder">
      <ul>
      dynamic elements here
      .....
      </ul>
    </li>
   <li class="folder">..more dynamic elements..</li>
 </ul>
```

```
$(.folder).append('<ul><li class="folder">NodeName</li></ul>');
```

So i know this is not the way it should be done because it is interpreted as a string, so i also tried with this:

```
$(.folder).append($(<ul><li class="folder">NodeName</li></ul>).folder());
```

and that gives me Object object has no method folder. 
So i am not really experienced with js and jQuery and i am not sure how can i append these elements to the tree. Both options add the list underneath the parent element, but all the classes and functionalities that come from the wijmo tree are not added to this appended elements.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
.append('<ul><li class="folder">NodeName</li></ul>');
```

supposed to be

```
.append('<ul><li class="folder">' + NodeName + '</li></ul>');
```

Comment: Thank you, i just used NodeName as an example node name, since i am getting the node node name from the json response i am using something like item.name for getting the node name, where item represents an single element from the json result.

Comment: Sure.. Replace that with `item.name` which should solve your problem

Comment: //$('#'+nodeID+'').append('<ul id="'+nodeID+'_children" class="wijmo-wijtree-list ui-helper-reset wijmo-wijtree-child" style="display: block;"><li class="folder wijmo-wijtree-item"><div role="treeitem" aria-expanded="false" aria-checked="false" aria-selected="false" class="wijmo-wijtree-node ui-state-default"><span class="ui-helper-clearfix wijmo-wijtree-inner ui-corner-all cHover"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-folder-collapsed">...<span class="wijmo-checkbox-icon"></span></div></div><a href="//" class="node" nodeID='+ item.nodeID +'>' + item.name + '</a></li></ul></span></div>');

Comment: `$('#'+nodeID+'')` can be changed to `$('#'+nodeID)`

Comment: `class="node" nodeID='+ item.nodeID +'>'` is supposed to be `class="node" nodeID="'+ item.nodeID +'">'`

Comment: This is the exact append that i am using but as you see the problem is that i am putting the whole html that should be generated by wijmo into the append. And this lacks functionalities like hover which is implemented by wijmo tree component also, and the 'node' class of the <a> element is not recognized etc,etc. I mean it is not a problem to post the whole html into the append, if the clases would be recognized. This is important because depending on the clases some other functions are called on other selectors.